# Sharepoint Connecting to TFS gives SSL error

Tags: sharepoint, ssl

i am trying to build a web part to display the TFS projects and i am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client and using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
 [like here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx)

This works perfectly in a sample web app , but the moment the code goes into a visual web part,
i get a SSL errors 
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure...

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Rajat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never work with TFS interactiong with Sharepoint. Needless to say that I didn't came across such problem. But here is the link which explains in detail on how a aspx page can interacts with the TFS.

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx

Have Great Day!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shahed. The blog you are referring to,is the exact one i looked up for my problem. ANyways , the problem was with Sharepoint unable to connect to a HTTPS, because of obvious Certificate issues. Though i got a resolution on a blog, i figured its better not to take chance with visualstudio.com (online tfs) and i got TFS configured on  one of my VM's. WORKS like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I got TFS configured on my VM ,which solved my problem, but i was unable to solve the original issue .